# vba - Handle worksheet change event before running macro

Tags: vba, excel

Assume an Excel worksheet with two vba `Sub` procedures:

- Sub1: A handler on worksheet changes

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
      'do something
  End Sub
  ```
- Sub2: A `Sub` which runs when clicking a button

When a user clicks the Sub2-button while editing a cell, both `Sub`s are executed in the order Sub2 (because he clicked the button) -> Sub1 (because the edit action was terminated).

How can I reverse this order?  I want to handle the worksheet change before running the `Sub` associated to the clicked button.

Both `Sub`s must remain unrelated.  Ie. if the Sub2-button is clicked and no cell editing is going on, only Sub2 should be executed.

Comment: Add a single cell value write on the worksheet as the first line of Sub2; e.g. range("a1") = range("a1").value then DoEvents. This executes the Worksheet_Change. Be careful with changing values, possibly use application.enableevents =false to avoid the Worksheet_Change running on top of itself. You can also call the Worksheet_Change if you add a cell as hte Target.

Comment: @Jeeped, I don't want to falsely trigger the `Worksheet_Change` handler if there was no change...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with this solution:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
    'handle worksheet changes here
End Sub
```

```
'Workaround to make sure other pending events (like worksheet changes) are handled first.
'It schedules handleButtonClick at the end of the event queue
Public Sub handleButtonClick ()
    Application.OnTime Now, "handleButtonClick_private"
End Sub

Private Sub handleButtonClick_private ()
    'handle button click here
End Sub
```

It works by deferring the actual handler to the end of the event queue.  Therefore, a possible pending worksheet change event will be handled before the actual handler is executed.

Answer (score 0):

It means `Sub2` make change in related Sheet of `Sub1`, Thus...

Use bellow approach:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'Edited
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "SheetName" Then
        'do something
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True 'Edited
End Sub 'Worksheet_Change
```

**Edited**

```
Sub Sub2
Application.EnableEvents = False
    'do something
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub 'Sub2
```

As a result, `Sub1` procedure runs only when the related sheet have activated, and when `Sub2` procedure is running, another Event procedures have not activated.

Comment: I dont see how this solves the problem.  I edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Piloos, I Edited above question, to be more clear and usable. Yours.